# Prompt user for how many conversions they wish to make

Tags: java

Write a program that contains the following two methods:

```
public static double celsiusToFahrenheit(double cels)             
public static double fahrenheitToCelsius(double fahr)
```

Both of these methods will return a converted temperature.  The main method will prompt a user for the number of conversions they would like to make.  Use that number for the counter control of a for loop. Make sure that the numeric output has one decimal place.

I have half the program with the converting but I do not know how to ask the user how many conversions that they want and how to lay them out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TempConverter{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

       double fahrenheit;
       double celsius;

       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("Enter the Degrees in Fahrenheit");
       fahrenheit = input.nextDouble();
       celsius = (5.0/9.0)*(fahrenheit - 32);
       System.out.println("The number of degrees of Fahrenheit: " + fahrenheit);
       System.out.println("Converted to Celsius is: " + celsius);//end convert to celsius

       System.out.println("Enter the Degrees in Celsius");
       celsius = input.nextDouble();
       fahrenheit = (9.0/5.0)* celsius + 32;
       System.out.println("The number of degrees of Celsius: " + celsius);
       System.out.println("Converted to Fahrenheit is: " + fahrenheit);
    }

}
```

Comment: Use your Scanner to read a number and the wrap your current code in a loop that runs that many times.

Comment: basically: `get intput; for (i = 0; i < input; i++) { prompt for/do conversion }`

Comment: System.out.print("How many conversions would you like to make: ");
 int conversions=input.nextInt();   how would you make a loop for conversions? if your gaining user input for  the conversions how would you set that up in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Take number of times as input using the scanner. Run a loop for that number and inside ask for temperature using scanner for Fahrenheit and Celsius.

Or run an infinite loop and ask to enter Fahrenhei and Celsius using scanner. If user enters END/QUIT you end the loop and exit.

Comment: It needs to be...How many conversions would you like to make? say the user says 3 so It'll prompt Conversion#1                                                                                           To convert from from celsius to farenheight press  1

Comment: To convert from farenheight to celsius press 2:     and then the user presses 1 or 2.                                                                                                               and then it'll ask for either the celsius or farenheight temperature and then below that it'll use a simple System.out.println statement. And then that's one conversion and it'll do that 3 times or however many times the user entered. I've never worked with methods before. How do you connect with the user input for conversions and then go through all those quesions inside the conversion statement?